# Spyder ipython console 'Home' tab or 'Ctrl+A' not working properly

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I am using spyder 3.2.2 with Anaconda 3.6 in Windows 10 OS.
Weird things happened here, when I am coding in the ipython console in spyder. I pressed 'Home' or 'Ctrl+A' to try to go back to the beginning of the line, but the cursor only goes to the second position of the line. 'End' or 'Ctrl+E' works fine here. Pressing 'Home' key twice will make the cursor go to the beginning of the line though, but it's so inconvenient then.

Here is the screen capture:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is caused by a [bug](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/207) in the `qtconsole` package.

Unfortunately we don't know how to fix it because we are unable to reproduce it. If you find a clear way to do it, please post a comment on the issue report referenced above.